# How to call a child action in the Home controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my controller and my Partial view is ProducDetails,when I call the child action method in the default Home controller like this  @Html.Action("DisplayProduct", product),I get it cannot work any idea?
public class ProductController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Product/

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Product> products = new List<Product>()
        {
            new Product { Id =1, Name ="Product 1", Description ="Description 1", Price = 10m},
            new Product { Id =2, Name ="Product 2", Description ="Description 2", Price = 20m},
            new Product { Id =3, Name ="Product 3", Description ="Description 3", Price = 30m},
            new Product { Id =4, Name ="Product 4", Description ="Description 4", Price = 40m}
        };
        return View(products);
    }

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult DisplayProduct(Product product)
    {

        return PartialView("ProductDetails", product);
   }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`Html.Action` is expecting to have route values at second argument instead of your custom model. That's why you will not receive your product object if you call `@Html.Action("DisplayProduct", product)` immediatly.

If you want to get over it, you will need to send route values instead of your object when calling Html.Action. You can use this sample with an anonymous object :

```
@Html.Action("DisplayProduct", new { product.Id, product.Name, product.Description, product.Price } ) ;
```

**EDIT :**

If you're doing anything but returning to *"ProductDetails"* view on your action, why don't you use `Html.RenderPartial` immediatly instead of using  `Html.Action`:

```
@{
    Html.RenderPartial("ProductDetails", product) ; 
}
```

Comment: I am returning this values as a list like @foreach(var product in Model){ Html.Action("DisplayProduct", new { product.Id, product.Name, product.Description, product.Price } ) ; and the model is null when i debug it any idea?